# Use csv python rows and columns

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary

Hey I'm trying to create a dictionary by using the built in module csv in python. Essentially it is an excel file named weather.csv where the key in the row dictionary is the column header, and the value is the value from that row. I am stuck because I cannot get the code to run multiple columns to generate two dictionaries simultaneously. Also, i get a key error where it says print row['col_list'] which I do not understand why it is occurring. The col_list are the headers for each row. Here is my code thus far:

```
import csv
def read_file(filename, col_list):
    filename = 'weather.csv'
    with open('weather.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)      
        for row in reader:               
            print row['col_list']
```

This is what I would like my output to be. I think it is pretty simple what I am missing, but I am having difficulties figuring it out.

```
print read_file('weather.csv', ['TemperatureF', 'VisibilityMPH'])
{'TemperatureF': [30.9, 32.0, 32.0, 32.0, 32.0, 30.9 ...],
'VisibilityMPH': [10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 4.0, 2.5 ...]}
```

Comment: This looks like a good fit for `pandas`. Try importing your CSV with `pandas.read_csv` and then convert that to a dictionary with `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()`

Comment: Some example input data would make any proposed answer much easier to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a dictionary with keys for each column heading and a list for all the values that column contains? For example --

```
import csv

def read_file(filename, col_list, data={}):

    with open('weather.csv', 'r') as f:

        reader = csv.DictReader(f)      
        for num, row in enumerate(reader):
            if num == 0: continue # skip if it's the first row, which has the headings
            for col in col_list:
                if not data.get(col): data[col] = list()
                data[col].append(row[col])

    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `pandas`, I think it would be a better fit for this task than the `csv` module.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=col_list)
dict_ = df.to_dict()
```